# Magento 2.4.3 + Redis(7?)

Tags: magento2.4.3, redis

In my test environment (Ubuntu 20.04, PHP7.4, Percona 8.0, Varnish 6.5) I've just installed redis (backend, page cache and sessions) without thinking much about its version. And of course it's of version 7.02. I know Magento 2.4.3 requires Redis 6.0 but I haven't noted any problems with version 7.02. Does anybody has any experience running Magento 2.4.3 with Redis 7.0 in live environment under heavier load?

Answer (score 0):

Redis 7 is so fresh for the real experience of using in production. But based on change log i don't see any reason to don't try it on production as well. I don't see any incompatible changes that might affect to compatibility.

I have 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 with Redis 7 on staging environment and didn't find any issues.

P.S. I suggest to try MariaDB instead of Percona. FYI: Magento Cloud uses MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any clear advantages for using MariaDB over Percona? I had chosen Percona mainly because of XtraBackup and ease of doing proper backups of db...